# SWFUpload (uploadify) upload >2GB+ Issue, flash questions about integers

Tags: flash

I was trying to upload files via Uploadify, which is using SWFUpload. Then I got some problems when uploading files >4GB+, so started digging. I ended up with result that the problem is in SWFUpload. (I am not about to use this for my large files to upload, just the curious question)

It looks like SWFUpload has its limit at 2147483647 bytes. But I could sucessfully upload a 2.9GB file. I've contacted the developer and he told me, that I should try to compile it with newer Flash player 10, 11 or 11.7 (SWFUpload is compiled under Flash Player 9) (but he does not remember more, because stopped developing this plugin years ago and he is confused how I could upload 2.9GB file). I've downloaded everything compiled it under 32bit windows and newest version of Flash Player, nothing changed. Variables are :Number, so it should take number bigger than 2147483647, but no success.

(Please note: I dont know much about Flash)

So the question is: Where does this limit come from? Is this 32/64bit compiler, or 32/64bit Flash Player? or 32/64bit browser? Are there even x64 browsers?

Comment: But I could sucessfully upload a 2.9GB file - how?

Comment: Physical I/O requests on a 32 bit application are limited to 2GB/4BG with LFS. That is, only what it can retain in memory. A chunked upload would be fine.

Comment: Servers also often have a maximum filesize limitation in their configuration. That is why I ask how you uploaded 2.9 GB file.

Comment: What do you mean by "Servers also often have a maximum filesize limitation in their configuration."? (My server is fine configured to take files up to 10GB). I dont know how, but I've uploaded, thats why I am disappointed. I will try to upload again 2.9GB file, lets see it :)

Comment: Again tested and uploaded 2.9GB file, its fine there on the server... without corruptions. While Flash event traces just 2GB and uploads up to 4GB file.. holy crap is that flash ^^

Comment: So... you uploaded with multi-part file to the server, how? using javascript? CURL?

Comment: No multi-part just 1 file complete 2.9GB large..

Comment: SWFUpload uses multi-part form data. have you port sniffed it with fiddler? do you get any errors, or does it crash?

Comment: What does mean multi-part? I dont know how it works.

Comment: @WigglerJtag Do you know any other that is able to upload the file that has size more then 2 GB?because i also have the same problem.

Comment: You have to use HTML5 uploadify or plupload (but forget IE < 10 compatibility), I am using XHR to send data directly to my webserver (IE 9 does not work) (not through php, not flash) so I can send data up to 20GB [web browser limitation]

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing files larger than 2GB you should break up the data byte array into multiple uploads and re-assemble the files on the server. Even commercial upload services like dropbox limit uploads to 2GB due to inconsistent ability for all users to go over that size.

You can check the memory limit imposed by the browser: https://superuser.com/questions/354725/how-do-i-change-the-amount-of-memory-flash-can-use-in-chrome

Large uploads can all be accomplished with forms/js now. Particularly JQueryForm will help you out.

**Limitation could be from anywhere:**

Memory available to the flash plugin as limited by the browser encapsulating it (for security reasons).

Memory available to the client machine.

Memory available on the server.

Server Misconfiguration.

The initial version of as3 used uint instead of number thus maxed out at 4BG for the file reference object because numbers larger than that were unrepresentable.

Timeout: the server simply times out the execution due to settings.

Comment: It is AS3 and I've tried uint and still same problem :/ Thanks for your reply, interesting one.

Comment: It was as3 that was flawed upon initial release.

Comment: You still never said what the problem is. what errors do you get?

Comment: The problem is selecting bigger file than 4.2GB gives an error "the file is empty", tried to upload now 4.1GB file, did not upload, no error.

Comment: So the request does not go out or what?

Comment: I dont know, it just acts like it is sending everything but then it does not store it. Im not experienced with this Flash stuff, I cant say whats exactly the problem. Could you compile it and test it?

Comment: Get fiddler and see if it's even going out http://fiddler2.com/ if not, its a flaw in the upload actionscript/memory management wont allow it. I updated my answer for finding out the limit.